# Testing private functions with junit and mockk in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, mvvm, junit, mockk

How do I test a private function called in the init block using junit and mockk in Kotlin?

Example:

```
class viewModel(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {
  
  init {
    doSomething()
  }

  private fun doSomething() = viewModelScope.launch {
    //do something with the repository
  }
}
```

Actually I would not like to change the function to public, because it should only be executed in the init block.

Comment: Most developers believe we shouldn't test private methods because they're a mere implementation detail that should be able to change as long as it has no publicly visible effect.

Comment: Okay, is this bad design of the code to be tested because I can't test it?

Comment: Not necessarily, it's just that "the code to be tested" is not the private function itself, but the public constructor which uses this private function.

Answer (score 1):

You test a private function by making it accessible. It's really that simple. Either `public` or `internal` will do in this case. You can  add an annotation like `@VisibleForTesting` to mark it as test-visible only, and some IDEs will even give you a warning if you use such a function outside its container (e.g. class).